# smoothScrollToPositionFromTop invokes onScroll method on onScrollListener even when onScrollListener is assigned after scrolling duration

Tags: android, android-listview, smooth-scrolling

I am try to integrate 2 listviews in my activity such that when an item is clicked on one listview, the other will smoothly scroll to the clicked position. This should work the opposite way also, i.e. if a second listview item is clicked then the first listview should smoothly scroll to the position.

I have tried to call smoothScrollToPositionFromTop for my second listview, before which I set the onScrollListener as null and also set a variable (this variable is supposed to stop the second scrolllistener) and I use postDelayed to reset the onScrollListener to the second listview once my scrolling is done. But what happens is that even if I keep the smoothScroll duration as 500, and set the postdelayed duration as 9000 (got carried away trying), the onscroll method is called for the second listview after 9000ms !!! Is there is way to clear the scroll events that are being posted as soon as the onscrolllistener is set ???

Simply put, I just want to disable onScrollListener for the second listview while I smoothscroll it programatically and same for the first listview.

My code is given below:

```
   final int temp=(Integer)animQueueObj;
        list.setOnScrollListener(null);
        list.smoothScrollToPositionFromTop(temp,0,500);

        list.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

            @Override   //THIS part is to fix a bug with smoothscrollToPositionfromtop http://stackoverflow.com/a/15828993/2138983
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
                if(scrollState==OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE){
                    list.setOnScrollListener(null);
                    list.smoothScrollToPositionFromTop(temp,0,0);
                          //POINT X
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            }
        });
        list.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 

            @Override
            public void run() {
                mListScrollListen = true;
                //list.smoothScrollBy(0, 0);
                list.setOnScrollListener(mListScrollIstener);  //I tried writing these lines at point X also to no avail
            }
        }, 9000);
```