# `ListView` not scrolling to exact position when a few list item are of big height

Tags: android-listview, android

I'm using `ListView` to display my dynamic content. Based on selected option, I've to scroll to some specified position in `ListView`. This works great when the list item height is not that big, i.e. it covers the whole screen. But when big height item are present in list, the scroll doesn't take me to proper position, instead it takes to some in between position. I tried using both of the following but same result.

```
listView.smoothScrollToPosition(myItems.indexOf(thisItem));
listView.setSelection(myItems().indexOf(thisItem));
```

Can anybody point the possible cause of the issue and also give some suggestions.

Comment: Seems like a weird issue. Maybe time to move over to RecyclerView :P

Comment: @AmaJayJB It's not an appropriate time for me for this. Any other suggesion?

Comment: Only thing I can think of, if what you doing isnt working, would maybe use the smoothScrollByOffset and insert the height of the big item as the offset. Hopefully that will scroll to the correct space. Let me know if it works?

Comment: As data is dynamic, so I can't have the height of each item.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I am not sure. Good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workaround suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14479078/smoothscrolltopositionfromtop-is-not-always-working-like-it-should/20997828#20997828) worked for me except that I called both functions, `smoothScrollToPosition` and `setSelection`, sequentially instead of using `OnScrollListener`. Though its not giving smooth scrolling effect but it's fulfilling my requirement. If any body can suggest a more proper solution, it's welcomed.