# Animate EditText out of a window

Tags: java, android, jquery-animate

I have a RelativeLayout with a "search bar" (EditText) and a ListView under it:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etSearch"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:inputType="text" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/listview_selector" >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

After the user "searches" I want the EditText to animate out of the screen and the ListView to push to the top. I put together a *very* rough GIF of what I need:

[image]

Does anyone have an idea on how I can accomplish this? thanks

**UPDATE**

I found out how to make the EditText animate out of the screen with this:

slide_out_top.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="-100%" android:duration="600"/>
</set>
```

and then using it on the EditText like this:

```
mSlideOutTop = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_out_top);
et.startAnimation(mSlideOutTop);
```

but then the ListView stays at its current height. What I want is for the ListView to extend to the top as the EditText animates out.

Comment: Have you tried  changing the visibility of edittext?

Comment: of course but that doesn't shift it up, it just hides it and the ListView just jumps up

Comment: try using translate animation for your edittext.

Comment: I updated my answer, the EditText is animating out, but I want the ListView to extend up to fill the screen now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add TranslateAnimation to the ViewGroup( which is LinearLayout for you), the y-axis moving distance is the hight of the editText View. Then trigger this animation when you need. (update: just thought this way may create a blank bar at bottom, bad idea)

I have an another tricky idea.

set the EditText view in the ListView with position 0 , then simply call the smoothScrollToPostion(1) method to scroll.
see this may help you
[smoothScrollToPositionFromTop() is not always working like it should](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14479078/smoothscrolltopositionfromtop-is-not-always-working-like-it-should)

Comment: I used Animation and the EditText successfully animates out of the screen. BUT, the ListView isn't expanding with it. Any ideas? I updated my answer btw

Comment: listview's height doesn't change, the measure function wasn't call will editText slide out.

Comment: I understand why the height doesn't change, but I'm trying to figure out how to make it scale to the top

Comment: it won't change , you didn't scale the EditText view , animation just draw it to somewhere else, the real position of that view still there, so the listView can't popup.

Comment: So if I change the EditText view down to 0, the ListView will expand up?

Comment: yes , but if you use ValueAnimator to set the height of EditText dynamically , it will be ugly.... I think extend ListView,  and use my second idea will be ok.

Comment: unfortunately your send suggestion won't work because I want to be able to open/close the EditText in any position of the ListView, not just the top

Comment: sorry for misunderstood. If so, I need some time to think about the better idea :)

Comment: no problem, I'm still looking, thanks for the help :)