# Get listview item position after soft keyboard shown

Tags: android, listview, location, on-screen-keyboard

I have a ListView, it is under action bar and above an EditText.
See picture:
[image: The original looking]

The list view items have random height according to its content.

When click list view item, I need to focus on EditText and open soft keyboard, meanwhile I want the one being clicked to be at top of the list view, for example if I click item2, I want to see:

[image: After clicking an item]

For putting the clicked item to the top of listview, when clicking an item, I will get the clicked item View by its position, and call `view.getLocationOnScreen(locations)` to get its y location, and use this y minus actionbar's height, then I get the distance to scroll, at last call `listview.smoothScrollBy(distance, 100);`.

This approach works well after the soft keyboard being shown, as the list view's height will be fixed then; but it doesn't work well the first time I click a list view item, because at this point, the listview's height will be changed as the soft keyboard takes up some spaces, which causes when I use `view.getLocationOnScreen(locations)`, it returns the old position of the view, *old* means the position before the soft keyboard shown, I also tried to use `view.postDelayed(new Runnable() {//Gets view position here!}, 1000);`, but got the same *old* position.

So the question should be how to get the latest position after the keyboard shown?

I use `android:transcriptMode="normal"` for ListView and `adjustResize` for `windowSoftInputMode`.

EDIT:

Also tried `int firstVisiblePos = commentsListView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
        int offset = firstVisiblePos - clickedPosition;
        commentsListView.smoothScrollByOffset(offset);`, but still no helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`commentsListView.setSelection(clickedPosition + 1);`, got it, simply this works for me, although it has no animation (not smooth), it is good enough for me, for making the smooth scroll to position, use this answer [link][smoothScrollToPositionFromTop() is not always working like it should](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14479078/smoothscrolltopositionfromtop-is-not-always-working-like-it-should/20997828#20997828)

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to use the screen height to scroll the listView. You could use ListView's smoothScrollToPosition(int position) to scroll to a particular location in the list.

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't work for me, when I was trying to call `smoothScrollToPosition(0)`, it even cannot scroll to the first item of list view.