# Listview - How do I do a smooth scroll to top from the 10th item?

Tags: android, listview

I have the 10th item as the top visible one in the listview. I need to do smooth scroll to the top item. When I do the following, it just stays at around the 6th item from top, does not scroll to the top.

```
lstConvList.setSelectionFromTop(10, 30);
lstConvList.smoothScrollToPositionFromTop(0, 0, MyMessage.SCROLL_UP_DURATION);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20997828/5908572).

Quote:

> First call smothScrollToPositionFromTop(position) and then, when
>   scrolling has finished, call setSelection(position). The latter call
>   corrects the incomplete scrolling by jumping directly to the desired
>   position. Doing so the user still has the impression that it is being
>   animation-scrolled to this position.