# Android listview extra space at the end when scroll

Tags: android, listview, scroll

I have experienced strange behaviour with smooth scroll on listview.
I have 30 items in list. When I smooth scroll via

```
listview.smoothScrollToPositionFromTop(29, 0);
```

there will be some extra space at the end of screen. Actually listview shifts up a little. Image attached below. But if I scroll manually there will be no space. What can be done to resolve this behaviour?

[image: Image 1]

Here is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: in the layout: `android:padding="0px" android:margin="0px"`

Comment: Simply remove listview.smoothScrollToPositionFromTop(29, 0);

Comment: @LunarWatcher Problem still exits with zero padding and margin

Comment: @JaiminModi I intentionally want smooth scroll to 29th item.

Comment: Hi, I have same issue.

Comment: **just move to `RecyclerView`.** I have implemented same thing with `RecyclerView` and it working properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you have said, I think it's an Android issue.  It appears to be part of the animation for over scroll, it seems to get 'stuck' before completing the animation.  I've had similar experience with `SwipeToRefresh`, where the progress indicator doesn't fully disappear after refresh.

Anyway, you can workaround by turning off the animation

```
    listView.setOverScrollMode(View.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
```

Unfortunately, this loses the animation even if manually scrolled.  If you can live with that, I think this will fix your problem.

[AbsListView#setOverScrollMode(int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setOverScrollMode(int))

**EDIT:** (after original answer was accepted)

I have also found another work around.  This one preserves the over scroll animation.  Unfortunately, it has another drawback.  If the user auto scrolls before doing anything else, the same problem of the border at the bottom exists.  If the user manually scrolls to the bottom 1st, no problem from then on.  If the user auto scrolls and gets the border, then manually scrolls, no more problem.  So, here is the alternate method.

```
    Drawable drawable = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.invisible_footer, null);
    listView.setOverscrollFooter(drawable);
```

In the drawable folder, "invisible_footer.xml"

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:height="2dp"
    android:width="10dp"

    android:viewportWidth="10"
    android:viewportHeight="2">

    <!-- a horizontal line -->
    <path android:pathData="M 1 1 H 10"
        android:strokeColor="#00000000" android:strokeWidth="1" />

</vector>
```

[ListView.html#setOverscrollHeader()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setOverscrollHeader(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable))

This gives choices:

1. Lose over scroll animation
2. Retain animation but risk user seeing bottom border 1 time

Answer (score 1):

i have implemented. but, at initial first time it keep the padding at bottom but, from second time its working fine.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.socialintegration.ListAct">
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listTemp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"></ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

CODE :

```
public class ListAct extends AppCompatActivity {
ListView l;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);
    String str[] = new String[50];
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        str[i] = "poistion" + i;
    }
    ArrayAdapter adpt = new ArrayAdapter(ListAct.this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, str);
    l = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listTemp);
    l.setAdapter(adpt);

    l.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            l.smoothScrollToPositionFromTop(29, 0);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Bro, now i have taken 30 items and same issue with me.

Comment: i think it might be the default behavior of android or listview.

Comment: The issue is for the first time only..with above code.

Comment: I think that's Android issue but could not find any open or closed issue about it.

Comment: @JaiminModi you should edit your answer. Instead of saying that you fixed it, also write how. What did you do that is different from the original code?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to set the height of your ListView to `wrap_content` instead of `match_parent`?

Even in [this tutorial] all the attributes are set to `wrap_content`. So replace your ListView attributes on width and height to:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: did you try wrap content and margin/padding at 0px

Answer (score 1):

There is an other SO post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14479078/smoothscrolltopositionfromtop-is-not-always-working-like-it-should) which describes a similar problem. I guess the solution in that post should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

try this to your xml:

```
<ListView
android:id="@+id/listview"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="0dp"
android:clipToPadding="false"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ListView>
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior/>
```

Ok so try:
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"

Comment: ya, and also remove padding from your main parent layout.

Comment: This is same with my layout and has no padding

Answer (score 0):

**I strongly believe to move to `RecyclerView`.
If you don't want to move.
Here is work around. Just add this method to your activity, and call it.**

```
private void smoothScrollToTop(final int pos) {
    listView.smoothScrollToPositionFromTop(pos, 0);
    listView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            listView.smoothScrollToPosition(pos);
        }
    });
}
```

This is well tested. and worked for me. And here is output.

[image]

Comment: The solution handles empty spaces however it kind a jumps to the position rather than smooth scrolling.

Comment: @Alock Leo No first it will smooth scroll, then it will jump. So that, it's look like a smooth scrol